# ASP.net application deployment in Windows Azure

Tags: .net, azure

I have developed my application in C# (asp.net) using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2005. Can i deploy it using Windows Azure? Also can i migrate the same code from Visual Studio 2008 to 2010 and the same for SQL Server 2005 and 2005 ?
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

This is an older post but should get you pointed in the right direction:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/02/08/migrating-an-existing-asp-net-app-to-run-on-windows-azure.aspx

And yes, you should be able to migrate your solution from VS 2008 to 2010.  VS will run a conversion wizard and notify you of any changes.